# Why isn't lodash's _.unique returning unique objects when I pluck a field that is an object?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, unique, lodash

I'm using lodash's [_.unique](http://lodash.com/docs#uniq) and it's not working as expected.  I'm doing this:

```
uniqueByFocusIndex = _.unique(clickables, false, "focusIndex");
```

And as you can see in the image (look at the right), it's returning two elements with the same values for their `focusIndex`es.  I'd expect this to return one of the two, not both.  Is it because `_.unique` only works on primitives and not objects?

Click to expand: [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work because comparing objects is done by reference and returns false even if the objects' contents are the same.

Using a string for the callback will check those values using the `pluck` callback style, but comparison of those objects you have under that key will always be false.

I tried to find a way to do this with some other callback, but I think you would be better off just writing your own `uniq` function that fits your purposes.

Comment: Yeah I think you're on to something.  Check my answer for a solution, though.

Comment: @tieTYT I tried lots of different stuff to get it to work, but couldn't with how `uniq` is implemented. In your answer, even if you change one of the objects (`x` from 1 to 2) it still gives the same (now wrong) result.

Answer (score 9):

[`_.uniqWith`](https://lodash.com/docs#uniqWith) is what you might need so that you can do comparison using [`_.isEqual`](https://lodash.com/docs#isEqual)

`_.uniqWith(clickables, _.isEqual)`

It is suggested in the [docs](https://lodash.com/docs#uniqWith)

Answer (score 1):

apparently for lodash version 4.x.x _.uniq works with primitives, If you want to work with array of json's the use _.uniqBy

```
uniqueByFocusIndex = _.uniqBy(clickables,"focusIndex");
```