# Lodash _.uniq() with _.omit() returning reference rather than value?

Tags: javascript, debugging, this, lodash

I have the following, where I am try to reduce check for duplicate objects in an array by omitting the `$$hashKey`, since it's possible for an item to be added prior to having a `$hashKey` and I want to note the potential duplicate index and make the comparison without respecting the `$$hashKey`, returning an array that omits duplicates amongst all other values. Unfortunately, it seems that `_.omit(val, '$$hashKey')` is not guarding properly in this case.  Is there something I'm missing?  Is this a javascript reference vs. equality issue?

```
        var dupeIndex = -1;
        var stringParams = [{'name':'foo'},{'$$hashKey':'3XA','name':'foo'}];
        var stringParamsShallow = _.uniq( stringParams, function (val, key, array) {
            if ( ! val.hasOwnProperty('$$hashKey') ) {
              dupeIndex = key;
            }
            return _.omit(val, '$$hashKey');
          });
          // incorrectly returns `[{'name':'foo'},{'$$hashKey':'3XA','name':'foo'}]`
```

Comment: It can't be reduced in that way and still be helpful.  `_.uniq()` is returning `_.omit(val,'$$hashKey')` and at some point in the chain when comparing equivalence. It's failing to compare properly.  Updating with the unexpected response value.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/24591553/1269466 since you can reduce this to: _.uniq([{'name':'foo'},{'name':'foo'}])

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why isn't lodash's \_.unique returning unique objects when I pluck a field that is an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591236/why-isnt-lodashs-unique-returning-unique-objects-when-i-pluck-a-field-that-i)